# pasar de xlsx a csv en AIX

Tags: linux

Tengo que pasar un fichero en xlsx a csv en AIX pero no tengo ninguno comando para hacerlo tampoco es posible instalar ninguno. No esta instalado python y pearl no tiene la librería de spreadsheet.

No se puede instalar nada nuevo en el server.

¿queda alguna manera de convertir los xlsx?

Comment: No te lo voy a poner en una respuesta porque más allá de Linux, desconozco que otras tecnologías puedes utilizar, pero si sabes cuantas columnas tiene el excel solo tendrías que ir recorriendo las filas hasta que no leas más datos e ir obteniendo el valor de cada columna y escribiendolo en un nuevo fichero que guardes como csv. Es una idea...

Comment: y como accedo a la información del fichero ?

Comment: Como te decía en mi anterior comentario, no sé que opciones tienes para tratar el fichero. Deberías buscar en la tecnología que vayas a utilizar, como abrir un excel y recorrerlo. Inténtalo, investiga y cuando te encuentres con un nuevo problema edita la pregunta y te ayudamos. No te puedo decir más porque en las etiquetas solo has definido Linux, aunque en la pregunta indicas AIX, Python y Perl, ¿cuál de todas vas a usar? Lo que te comento, investiga e intentalo, es más satisfactorio si al final lo sacas por ti mismo. Y si no, ¡¡aquí estamos para ayudarte!!

Comment: no he puesto mas etiquetas por que no hay etiquetas de AIX perl or xlsx. No tengo opciones para abrir el fichero de eso se trata tengo opciones para tratar ficheros planos.

Comment: nose my bien en que tengo que apostar por que tampoco se si hay alguna opción que no he visto de allí la pregunta.

Comment: Si Perl no tiene instalado Spreadsheet y no puedes instalar nada es realmente dificil. Estás queriendo ver en la oscuridad sin ninguna luz.....a menos que haya alguna librería más en el servidor, pero con la información que has aportado, al menos por mi parte, desconozco la forma en la que puedes leer el archivo.